# List of SE sites associated with ours?

Tags: support

Lurking around our chat room, sometimes I saw some bot post a question, or anything outside our main site Anime.SE, like from Movies.SE or SciFi.SE, always with [anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime) tag, usually for id-request. So, how many SE sites are actually connected to us, and does our site also have the same thing? Have our questions been posted on other SE sites' chat room?

Comment: It'd be great to auto migrate these, idk if that is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sites are not exactly linked to our site. What actually happens is that we have a [set of feeds](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6697/maid-cafe-?tab=feeds) that were all added manually.
The sites listed on our [*All the animations!* feed](http://stackexchange.com/feeds/tagsets/77961/all-the-animations?sort=newest) are [SciFi and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), [Movies and TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) and [Japanese Language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/). More can be added, according to the needs we see fit.

As for other sites that post our content on their room, I am not aware of any way to search for feeds across rooms, so you'd have to check each of them individually.